# WCF cannot pass single reference object in method but list of reference object is OK

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, reference, poco

Today I'm having a very odd problem with WCF services that is making my head spin.

In my code I have two definitions in my WCF interface.

```
[OperationContract]
List<DOMAIN.Models.Configuration.PAEConfiguration> GetConfigurationList(Guid companyID);

[OperationContract]
DOMAIN.Models.Configuration.PAEConfiguration GetConfigurationByCompanyID(Guid companyID);
```

Which both obviously relate to the same define POCO class.

However, while the top LIST version works fine, I get the following error at compile time for the last call.

```
The type 'PAE.DOMAIN.Models.Configuration.PAEConfiguration' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'PAE.DOMAIN, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.
```

The first call works perfectly. The second results in a build error.

Obviously I'm finding this a little confusing as you'd imagine that if it was fine to pass as a List of x would be OK to be managed as x.

The source POCO class is

```
[DataContract]
public class PAEConfiguration : PAEConfigurationTemplate
{
    [DataMember]
    public Guid PAEConfigurationID { get; set; }
}
```

Which inherits this.

```
[DataContract]
public class PAEConfigurationTemplate
{
   [DataMember]
   public Guid CompanyID { get; set; }

   /* And lots more besides */

}
```

Comment: Does it fails on compile or in runtime?

Comment: It fails are compile time. I've corrected my question as a result :D

Comment: Is the PAEConfiguration marked up as a DataContract? Can we see the domain class?

Comment: Updated question in response. NOTE: I have simpler POCO classes that exhibit the same behavior.

Comment: @RobLeather Ok, this won't help you much, but i've created new WCF project, added you contracts, and it compiles and working fine, so it's might be some problems with you project|solution.

Comment: I'm getting that feeling Uriil. To be honest, I was hoping somebody would just have had a similar issue and could point me in the right direction. I've actually added the Domain project to the client application and this has made it happy. But I shouldn't have too and it's a bit of a work around. Sadly, time doesn't permit a more elegant examination of the problem.